# Help with Javascript Button on Opportunity

Tags: custom-button

I created a button on the opportunity that will change the stage to "Duplicate"
I need to be able to check that the opportunity is not already closed before changing the stage.  However, I can't get the if statement to work.  I'm receiving the error message "FALSE is not defined"

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 

var o = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity"); 

o.id = "{!Opportunity.Id}"; 

if ("{!Opportunity.IsClosed}" == FALSE){

o.StageName = "Duplicate"; 

}
else{
alert("Opportunity is closed.");
}

sforce.connection.update([o]); 

window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javscript, unlike Apex/Visualforce, is case-sensitive. See this screenshot of the developer console in chrome (F12 to access).

Lines starting with > are lines I wrote

< is output

[image: case sensitivity]

```
if ("{!Opportunity.IsClosed}" == false){
```

Should fix your trouble.